# Evaluate $\oint_C \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-1)^4} \mathrm dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$I=\oint_C \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-1)^4} \mathrm dz$$

where $z$ is a complex number.

Sources of confusion:

1. $C$ has not been given. Is such kind of a question possible?
2. Considering $z=1$ is within the limits of the contour

My answer is $I=\frac{8}{3}\pi i e^2$, while my book's answer is $I=\frac{8}{3}\pi i e^{-2}$

Answer (score 6):

Recalling [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):

$$
f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz
$$

Setting $n=3$ and defining $f(z)=e^{2z}$, and $a=1$:

$$
f^{(3)}(1) = \frac{3!}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-1)^{3+1}}dz
$$

From the definition of $f$ we have:
$$
f^{(3)}(1) = 8e^2
$$

So on one side we have the contour integral in your problem. Assuming again that $C$ is a counter-clock-wise contour that contains 1 in it's interior, we have:

$$
8e^2 = \frac{3!}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-1)^{3+1}}dz
$$

Thus:
$$
\oint_C \frac{e^{2z}}{(z-1)^{3+1}}dz = \frac{8}{3} e^2 \pi i
$$

So... I second your result. There could be a typo somewhere in the book or maybe a printing defect on your specific copy of it.

Answer (score 3):

Mefitico has answered comprehensively the second part of the question: however he left the first part somewhat incomplete, therefore my answer will focus on that part.

> 1. $C$ has not been given. Is such kind of a question possible?

**Yes, this question is perfectly answerable, even if you don't know the exact form of the contour, provided that the following characteristics of $C$ are known**:

1. defining the *interior of $C$* as the greatest open bounded plane set $G\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\partial{G}\subseteq C$ (the reason of higher complexity of this definition respect to the usual one will be clear in the discussion of next point) it is necessary that $1\in G$: this is due to the fact that the function $f(z)=e^{2z}/(z-1)^4$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$ therefore by [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem),
   $$
   \oint_C f(z)\mathrm{d}z=0,
   $$
   no matter how the structure of $C$ is. This is exactly the assumption made in the second part of the question: however, even this information alone is not sufficient. We need the following one.
2. It is necessary to know the [widing number (or index)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContourWindingNumber.html) $\mathrm{ind}(C,a)$ of the contour $C$ respect to the point $1\in\mathbb{C}$. This is due to the fact that the most general form of Cauchy's integral formula, the [homological Cauchy integral formula](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/34138), involves also this topological invariant, which intuitively describes how many times the contour $C$ "turns around" the point $1$. Stated for a generic point $a\in G$
   $$
   \mathrm{ind}(C,a)\,f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}z
   $$
   (see [1], §7.2 pp. 229-230 for an even more general version). 
   If $C$ is a simple closed curve, then $\mathrm{ind}(C,a)=\pm1$ (depending on the orientation chosen on $C$) and everything goes as explained in the answer by Mefitico, otherwise you must account for the non-unity value of the index.
   **Note**: the complexity higher than standard in the definition of $G$ is due to the fact that if $\mathrm{ind}(C,a)\neq\pm1$ then $C$ is not a simple continuous curve and therefore $\partial{G}\neq C$ since we cannot invoke Jordan's curve theorem.

[1] Burckel, Robert B. (1979), *An Introduction to Classical Complex Analysis*, Vol. 1, Lehrbücher und Monographien aus dem Gebiete der exakten Wissenschaften. Mathematische Reihe, Band 64, Basel–Stuttgart: Birkhäuser Verlag, p. 570, ISBN 3-7643-0989-X, MR 0555733, Zbl 0434.30001.